# RedisClusterException when trying to write using Celery

Tags: python, django, sockets, redis, redis-cluster

**My environment:**
I have three Ubuntu servers.
One server is used as a load balancer using Nginx.
The other two servers contain the exact same project (are identical apart from redis where one box is the master and other is the slave).

**The Programs/Applications I'm using**
Python,
Gunicorn,
Django,
Celery,
Redis,
Sentinel

**What My project does:**
I have a URL which takes in a GET request, does some logic regarding the request and saves into redis.

```
def save(key, value):
    conn = redis_cluster_connect()
    print conn
    conn.set(key, value)
    conn.set('bar','foo')
```

This was working fine when my connection was:

```
def redis_connect():
    print 'redis connected'
    return redis.Redis(host="xxx.xx.xxx.x", port=6380, db=1) # CHANGE TO THE REDIS PORT THAT IS ACTIVE
```

But when I use the cluster connection:

```
def redis_cluster_connect():
    startup_nodes = [{"host": "xxx.xx.xxx.x", "port": "6380"}]
    rc = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True)

return rc
```

**The Error I get:**

```
[2016-09-15 13:28:59,682: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: testapp.tasks.mobilise_stops[cc64c425-bd37-4896-b6ab-4319de5fb743]
    [2016-09-15 13:28:59,684: WARNING/Worker-1] Oh no! Task failed: RedisClusterException("ERROR sending 'cluster slots' command to redis server: {'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.x', 'port': '6380'}",)
    [2016-09-15 13:28:59,685: ERROR/MainProcess] Task testapp.tasks.mobilise_stops[cc64c425-bd37-4896-b6ab-4319de5fb743] raised unexpected: RedisClusterException("ERROR sending 'cluster slots' command to redis server: {'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.x', 'port': '6380'}",)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
        R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
        return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/var/www/gateway/venv/gateway/testapp/tasks.py", line 50, in mobilise_stops
        save(mobilise_stops.request.id, 'Success')
      File "/var/www/gateway/venv/gateway/testapp/tasks.py", line 28, in save
        conn = redis_cluster_connect()
      File "/var/www/gateway/venv/gateway/testapp/tasks.py", line 19, in redis_cluster_connect
        rc = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rediscluster/client.py", line 157, in __init__
        **kwargs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rediscluster/connection.py", line 83, in __init__
        self.nodes.initialize()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rediscluster/nodemanager.py", line 148, in initialize
        raise RedisClusterException("ERROR sending 'cluster slots' command to redis server: {0}".format(node))
    RedisClusterException: ERROR sending 'cluster slots' command to redis server: {'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.x', 'port': '6380'}
```

When I run redis-cli and set a variable on the master (on server 1) I can retrieve it on the slave (on server 2)

```
server 1:
xxx.xx.xxx.x:6380> set test 100
OK

server 2:
xxx.xx.xxx.x:6381> get test 
"100"
```

When I try doing the cluster slots command in the redis client I get the same error as the above.

```
xxx.xx.xxx.x:6380> cluster slots
(error) ERR unknown command 'cluster'
```

One thing to consider is my redis config file doesn't have a tcp socket, when I tried using tcp redis would not work. It gave me an error when I tried running redis. This was changed to the default Unixsocket that comes in the default redis.conf file

From:

```
tcp-backlog 511
```

To:

```
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running a redis cluster, so attempting to run redis-cluster only commands are going to fail.

Comment: Thanks that was it, I was confused between master - slave and redis cluster. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

For my case the problem was in version redis-py-cluster (1.3.4), after reinstallation to version 1.3.1 everything works well for me. I guess there was some issue that version of python package.